# Formatting is broken in chrome latest version

Tags: html, css

Links in web page is broken as below in chrome 39.0.2171.65]

[image: screen shot fron chrome 39.0.2171.65]

But it is working fine in  chrome version  38.0.2125.122 and all other browsers

[image]

Html

```
<div class="setleft"><a class="button " href="https://example.com"><span>Daily Diary</span></a></div>
<div class="setleft"><a id="tab" class="button " href="https://example.com"><span>Progress</span></a></div>
```

CSS

```
button, a.button, input[type='button'], input[type='submit'], input[type='reset'], a.eylog_green_button {
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
background-color: #EAEAEA;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#EAEAEA));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #EAEAEA);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #eaeaea);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #eaeaea);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #eaeaea);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #eaeaea);
/* filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#eaeaea); */
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-bottom-color: #AAA;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #555;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 700;
margin: 0;
padding: 8px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
vertical-align: middle;

}
```

If  i add `white-space: nowrap; it works fine.This issue exist in many places in my application.Why is this happend?.Is this solution or any other better solution there.

Comment: I believe that there is font-rendering bug in Chrome 39...still looking for the reference though.

Comment: This is a change or a bug in latest Chrome, probably on Windows. Can't reproduce a similar issue with chrome 38, but not 39.

Comment: @Paulie_D probably this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436340&q=word-wrap&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `white-space: nowrap;` anyway. If you don't, then you say "you can wrap this text if you want" but you can never be sure when the browser might want to wrap the text. So specifically saying "don't wrap" will make sure you always get what you want.